# How to use Result's column with Having clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure,

I want to use `HAVING` clause with columns `IsUserFruitEater` and `IsUserOnSite` but it says column not exists.

***Not sure how to use columns, there must be a way to use Stored Procedure result's columns...***

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Risks_GetFruitCratesForUser]
(
    @UserID VARCHAR(200),
    @URLFilter varchar(256)
)
AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Fruits.*
    ,FruitsCrate.* dbo.IsUserRegularFruitEater(@UserID, FruitsCrate.FutureID) AS 
    IsUserFruitEater
    ,dbo.IsUserOnSite(@UserID, FruitsCrate.FID) AS IsUserOnSite
    ,COALESCE(doThis.deeraw, - 1) AS deeraw
    ,COALESCE(doThat.HeroSheema, - 1) AS HeroSheema
    ,Jootey.deeraw * Jootey.HeroSheema AS BigBang
FROM someTable....
WHERE blahblah NOT NULL
    AND blahblah2 LIKE "abc"
HAVING Min(IsUserFruitEater) > 0
    OR Min(IsUserOnSite) > 0
```

Comment: You don't have `GROUP BY` which is required for `HAVING`. So you can just put these conditions in WHERE clause: `WHERE dbo.IsUserOnSite(@UserID, FruitsCrate.FID) > 0 AND ...`

Comment: You're missing a comma `FruitsCrate.* dbo.IsUserRegularFruitEater`

Comment: @Bulat `Having` is usually used with a `group by` but it is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery and `where` clause:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Fruits.*, FruitsCrate.*
            dbo.IsUserRegularFruitEater(@UserID, FruitsCrate.FutureID) AS IsUserFruitEater,
            dbo.IsUserOnSite(@UserID, FruitsCrate.FID) AS IsUserOnSite,
            COALESCE(doThis.deeraw, -1) As deeraw  , COALESCE(doThat.HeroSheema, -1) As HeroSheema,
            Jootey.deeraw * Jootey.HeroSheema As BigBang
      From someTable....
      WHERE blahblah NOT NULL AND blahblah2 LIKE "abc"
     ) t
WHERE IsUserFruitEater > 0 or IsUserOnSite > 0;
```

I'm not sure what the `min()` is for.  You don't have a `group by`, which is the problem with using the `having` clause.

Comment: exactly what was I after, thank you, accepted in 15 min